# iOS 13+ ionic 4 iOS app stuck at splash screen

Tags: cordova, ionic4, ios13

config.xml

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.leo9.gameofplan" version="0.0.4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Game Of Plan</name>
    <description>The Game of Plan app is designed to: Capture your Thoughts and Feelings and convert it into Tangible Action Plan.</description>
    <author email="info@leo9studio.com" href="https://leo9studio.com/">Le9studio Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
    <preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 Google" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-secure-storage" spec="^3.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="^3.0.2" />
</widget>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Game of Plan</title>

  <base href="." />

  <meta name="viewport"
    content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="font-src 'self' data:; img-src * data:; default-src gap://ready file://* *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' * ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />


  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />

  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

here i am attaching my config.xml and index.html file.

The submitted App is rejected from App Store because app is stuck at splash screen in ios13+ devices.i tried degrading the splash screen plugin but its not working and also added some splash screen related config line into config.xml that is also not working.

what should be the solution?

Comment: I'm currently working on this... so I will let you know the answer once I have it. One thing I know for sure... if you remove "<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />", it will start working again. This has something to do with the UIWebView removal.

Comment: doesnt work for me even after removing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Cordova app. I was able to fix using following steps:

Install these plugins along with your other plugins:

1. "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.0.0"
2. "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": "^1.2.1"
3. cordova plugin add https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix
4. Remove iOS platform
5. Add iOS platform 5.1.1
6. Add this code in config.xml file inside the "platform name="ios"> tag

```
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />

<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

It will fix the both splash screen stuck issue and apple warning issue.

Comment: Not able to install "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.0.0". Did you face nay issues while installing the plugins?

Comment: @JobinsJohn I did not face such issue. Please can you share the error while installing this plugin ?